# Existing Azure Database with Entity Framework 6 Alpha 2

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-6

I have a database on azure where clustered indices are required. I would like to use Entity-Framework 6 Alpha 2, because I would like to use the new async features. When I test it on my local machine with SQL Express 2012 everything is fine, but when I try it with my azure database I get the following error:

Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and try again.

I have no idea what to do, because when I test it with an empty database every primary key is a clustered index.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Would you add a bit clarification on your situation with "Existing Database on Windows Azure" and using with EF 6? First of all - are you using EF CodeFirst, ModelFirst, DatabaseFirst?
Then if you really have existing database, how did you create it? DB + Schema manually, using some wizard (SSMS, SQL Azure Migration Wizard, EF CodeFirst created it, etc?). How this existing DB ended being in Azure?

Then trace down the full error message, check for which table it happens and manually add the clustered index on that table. It is true that every primary key you create in SQL Server, by default is also a CLUSTERED. But if the table was created first, then the Primary Key was added as separate DDL statement (ALTER TABLE ....) it might not have been created as CLUSTERED.

So, the message is pretty clear - please create clustered index first. Find out which table is SQL Azure complaining about and create a clustered index on it. If it hasn't Primary Key, just add one as CLUSTERD:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Individual]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Individual_CustomerID]
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
[CustomerID] ASC
)
```

If it has a primary key - check which columns are included, drop it, and recreate it as clustered.